# add UIViewController in subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I don't know if this is the right key to search "add UIViewController in subview".
As what you can see in my image ,there are two ViewController, the main and the second controller. Inside the main controller there is a UIView(blue background color). Inside in UIView, I want to add the second ViewController in my UIView. I have this code but It didn't work.

[image]

here's my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SampleViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    SampleViewController * sample = [[SampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:nil];
    sample.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.testView.bounds.size.width, self.testView.bounds.size.height);
    [self.testView addSubview:sample.view];
} 

@end
```

I want to know if this is possible? I know `initWithNibName:` works in xib file, I don't the exact term to search in google about this. I'm just trying to experiment something if this is possible in IOS. Hoping you understand what I'm trying to do. Hoping for your advice. Thanks in advance

**here's my update**

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;
@property(strong,nonatomic) SampleViewController * samples;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;
SampleViewController * sample = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SampleViewController"]; 
// SampleViewController * sample = [[SampleViewController alloc] //initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:nil];

[self displayContentController:sample];
//commented the below line because it is not needed here, use it when you want to remove        
//child view from parent.
 //[self hideContentController:sample];

}

- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
    [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
    content.view.bounds = self.testView.bounds;                 //2
    [self.testView addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}


- (void) hideContentController: (UIViewController*) content
{
    [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // 1
    [content.view removeFromSuperview];            // 2
    [content removeFromParentViewController];      // 3
}
```

I always get this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/ace/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/035D6DD6-B6A5-4213-9FCA-ECE06ED837EC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EB07DD14-A6FF-4CF5-A369-45D6DBD7C0ED/Addsubviewcontroller.app> (loaded)' with name 'SampleViewController''
```

I think, its looking for a nib. I didn't implement a nib here.

Comment: learn through this http://www.objc.io/issue-12/custom-container-view-controller-transitions.html

Comment: @user3818576 I edited my answer as per your needs, please make it use and let me know, if i can troubleshoot it more.

Comment: @user3818576  1. You are working with nib files or storyboard?

Comment: storyboard. I don't have nib file

Comment: @user3818576 I edited your code finally, please make it use and let me know.

Comment: I'm almost losing hope of this, But when you edit it. Thank you very much @SandeepAhuja. Thank you,Thank you,Thank you! hahaha.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should use Child containment concept, here MainViewController is a parent view controller and you want  to add child view controller view as a subview on Main View Controller.

**Adding and Removing a Child**

```
//call displayContentController to add SampleViewCOntroller view to mainViewcontroller
 [self displayContentController:sampleVCObject];

// write this method in MainViewController
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
   content.view.bounds = testView.bounds;                 //2
   [testView addSubview:content.view];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}
```

Here’s what the code does:

It calls the container’s addChildViewController: method to add the child. Calling the addChildViewController: method also calls the child’s willMoveToParentViewController: method automatically.
It accesses the child’s view property to retrieve the view and adds it to its own view hierarchy. The container sets the child’s size and position before adding the view; containers always choose where the child’s content appears. Although this example does this by explicitly setting the frame, you could also use layout constraints to determine the view’s position.
It explicitly calls the child’s didMoveToParentViewController: method to signal that the operation is complete.

```
//you can also write this method in MainViewController to remove the child VC you added before.
- (void) hideContentController: (UIViewController*) content
{
   [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // 1
   [content.view removeFromSuperview];            // 2
   [content removeFromParentViewController];      // 3
}
```

For more details, please refer to apple doc: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

**Configuring a Container in Interface Builder, for those who don't want to write code.**

To create a parent-child container relationship at design time, add a container view object to your storyboard scene, as shown in Figure 5-3. A container view object is a placeholder object that represents the contents of a child view controller. Use that view to size and position the child’s root view in relation to the other views in the container.

[image: Adding a container view in Interface Builder]
When you load a view controller with one or more container views, Interface Builder also loads the child view controllers associated with those views. The children must be instantiated at the same time as the parent so that the appropriate parent-child relationships can be created.

Comment: @user3818576 read this doc carefully, will solve your problem and helps to get inside of the matter for future use.

Comment: hello Sandeep. I have this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle". I think the nib file

Comment: @user3818576 Please check you have set StoryBoard ID "SampleViewController" in storyboard and also cross check the name. Also check whether it is added to compile target or not. and also check view and subviews are proper hooked to their IBOutlets or not.

Comment: Please see my update post. I think I'm already in the right path. right?

Answer (score 13):

You can do this simply by using StoryBoards

- Open storyboards and select the view controller in which your Blue view is present, open Utilities search for ContainerView and drag it into your blue view, this will automatically adds an view controller that acts as child view for your view. You can resize your container view in size inspector.

[image]

Comment: hello raki. This work fine for me but I want to know how this work programmatically. Thanks for your answer. I learn from you here

Comment: all other answers are for doing it programatically...:)

Answer (score 7):

I've resolved the problem about the uiview on second uiviewcontroller.
Follow the code that I've used:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *sb = (SecondViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sb"];

sb.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];    
[sb willMoveToParentViewController:self];

[self.view addSubview:sb.view];

[self addChildViewController:sb];
[sb didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I hope to help you.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

```
SampleViewController * sample = [[SampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:nil];
sample.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.testView.bounds.size.width, self.testView.bounds.size.height);

[self addChildViewController:sample];
[self.testView addSubview:sample.view];
```

Comment: I got errors here. Sorry. But when I replace initwithnibname to init. There are no errors but the output is empty in my uiview.

Comment: here is the error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle". I think the nib file, I don't know about this. sorry noob here

Comment: @user3818576 Yes, you need do set it with Xib.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a childViewController to UIViewController since iOS5..
it is a great way to maker smaller, more reusable viewControllers, I also really like it.

you're really close, but you just need a couple more lines of code..

```
///
 [self addChildViewController:sample];

 [self.testView addSubview:sample.view]; //you already have this..

 [sample didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

In you viewWillDisappear:  or one of the other teardown methods you'll need to clean up like this:

```
//we'll need another pointer to sample, make it an iVar / property..
   [sample willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // 1
   [sample removeFromSuperview];            // 2
   [sample removeFromParentViewController];      // 3
```

You can read the Apple docs on containing child viewControllers here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: hello jef, I have the same error with other answer. I'm still trying to figure out how to work on this error. "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle"

Comment: the initialiser you are trying to use here initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:nil specifies a file SampleViewController.xib .if you don't have such file then change nibName Argument to nil there..

Answer (score 2):

I'm tring to adding UIViewController in subview, and this work.
On UIViewController I've added 2 button, in .h file:

```
-(IBAction)matchButtonAction:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)closeButtonAction:(id)sender;
```

And in .m file:

```
-(IBAction)matchButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"matchButtonAction");
}
-(IBAction)closeButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"closeButtonAction");
}
```

but I don't see the log.

I need to add same parameter on UIViewController instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier?

How to resolve the problem?

My UIViewController initialization is:

```
AlertDialogViewController *alertDialogView = (AlertDialogViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"alertDialogView"];         
        [alertDialogView willMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [viewController.view addSubview:alertDialogView.view];
        [viewController addChildViewController:alertDialogView];
        [alertDialogView didMoveToParentViewController:viewController];
```

Comment: Can you tell how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Since your view controller is in storyboard you should use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to get the VC from storyboard.

```
SampleViewController * sample = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IdOfSampleViewController"];
sample.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.testView.bounds.size.width, self.testView.bounds.size.height);
[self.testView addSubview:sample.view];
```

Don't forget the add the **identifier** for the `SampleViewController` in storyboard

Comment: I get no error here but I when I add button in my second ViewController. I get an error in the main.

Comment: On clicking button? What error? Probably it because of SampleViewController is deallocating.

Comment: You should prevent the deallocation by making `sample`as an instance variable of your mainVC or add it as childViewController also will work as suggested by others here

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm still trying to figure out what others trying to implement. About the errors. It stop here "return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));" in the app delegate main.

Comment: make `sample` as instance variable and give a try

Comment: hello @anil, the only things that I miss is this "UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;" then I combined the code of other answer here. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've try to use this code:

SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

```
 secondViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mySubView.bounds.size.width, self.mySubView.bounds.size.height);

 [self addChildViewController:secondViewController];
 [self.viewDialogSolution addSubview:secondViewController.view];
```

but I see only myview not the layout of secondViewController.

Ho to resolve the probleam?

Thanks a lot

Comment: ok, now  I see the uiviewcontroller in my principal view, but how to see the uiview content in uiviewcontroller?
In myuiviewcontroller i've setted a uiview with text, how to see it in my principal view?

Comment: I've setted a viewvontroller red color background , I see the red color but I don't see the uiview? I need to link the 2 viewcontroller? I've created only layout  of the second viewcontroller and stop, I must to do something?

Comment: Did you use UIStoryboard?

Answer (score 0):

let controller:SecondViewController = 
self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! 
SecondViewController

controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds

controller.willMove(toParent: self)

self.view.addSubview(controller.view)

self.addChild(controller)

controller.didMove(toParent: self)