# Taking code from UIViewController to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, mapbox

I'm looking create this map inside a UIView. Would this be possible? If so can you tell me how I can take this code to a UIView from UIViewController. I'm trying to put a MapBox map into a UIView and there are only instructions on how to import it into a UIViewController

How would this code look as a UIView class:

```
import Mapbox

class mapboxMap: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

var mapView: MGLMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

    // set the map's center coordinate
    mapView.setCenterCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7326808,
        longitude: -73.9843407),
        zoomLevel: 10, animated: false)
    view.addSubview(mapView)

    // Set the delegate property of our map view to self after instantiating it.
    mapView.delegate = self

    // Declare the marker `hello` and set its coordinates, title, and subtitle
    let hello = MGLPointAnnotation()
    hello.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7326808, longitude: -73.9843407)
    hello.title = "Hello world!"
    hello.subtitle = "Welcome to my marker"
    mapView.addAnnotation(hello)

    let hello2 = MGLPointAnnotation()
    hello2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7526808, longitude: -73.9843407)
    hello2.title = "Hello world!"
    hello2.subtitle = "Welcome to my marker"
    mapView.addAnnotation(hello2)


}

// Use the default marker; see our custom marker example for more information
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, imageForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
    return nil
}

func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Wait a bit before setting a new camera.

    // Create a camera that rotates around the same center point, back to 0°.
    // `fromDistance:` is meters above mean sea level that an eye would have to be in order to see what the map view is showing.
    let camera = MGLMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: mapView.centerCoordinate, fromDistance: 9000, pitch: 45, heading: 0)

    // Animate the camera movement over 5 seconds.
    mapView.setCamera(camera, withDuration: 2.5, animationTimingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut))
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to do is "add UIViewController in subview". Try to use  [Container view Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html). And  following thread may helpful to you.

[add UIViewController in subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614776/add-uiviewcontroller-in-subview)