# IOS: Popover Controllers in Storyboard and Class

Tags: ios, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to use a popover controller for some extra navigation in the app. Since storyboard does not seem to have a separate popover controller, I created a UIViewController in storyboard.  Then I created a popover class, popoverVC.  The popover class does not appear in the drop down list of classes within identity inspector for the VC in storyboard, but when I typed it in, it seemed to take, i.e. upon closing and re-opening storyboard, the VC is still associated with the popover class.

However, when I try to Ctrl-click drag from elements in the VC in storyboard to methods or properties in the popoverVC class in Assistant Editor, it does not take.

What is the proper way to link a ViewController in storyboard with a class?  As a related question, although I set the width of the VC as narrow in storyboard, the app is ignoring that width and loading the popover full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be achieved through storyboards alone, instead apply the child container concept.

You should create and add a `UIView` (the container) to your viewcontroller that should contain the popover, and add the view of the popover viewcontroller to said container.

Now there are three things you should perform in specific order, namely:

1) call `addChildViewController:` on the containing viewcontroller with the popover viewcontroller.

2) call `addSubview:` on the container view and add the popover viewcontroller view.

3) call `didMoveToParentViewController:` on the popover viewcontroller with the containing viewcontroller.

Similarly, when removing the viewcontroller perform the following:

1) call `willMoveToParentViewController:` on the popover viewcontroller with `nil` to remove the parent connection.

2) call `removeFromSuperview` on the popover viewcontroller' view.

3) finally call `removeFromParentViewController` on the popover viewcontroller.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614855/4019540) for details.